# Scala extracting only certain characters

Tags: regex, scala

I am taking in line by line in Scala as a string, and I want to be able to remove all characters that don't belong to some arbitrary collection of letters S.

Would I do val pattern = S.r? And how would I parse a line to remove all characters not in S?

Comment: For future reference it is helpful to add the input you have, what you have tried, any error messages, and the expected output to your question. In this case "remove all characters that don't belong to some arbitrary collection of letters S" is fairly straight forward but that is not always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filterNot` to remove any character in a collection.

```
scala> val vowels = Set("a","e","i","o","u")
vowels: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(e, u, a, i, o)

scala> val line = """I am taking in line by line in Scala as a string, and I want to be able to remove all characters that don't belong to some arbitrary collection of letters S."""
line: String = I am taking in line by line in Scala as a string, and I want to be able to remove all characters that don't belong to some arbitrary collection of letters S.

scala> line.filterNot(x => vowels.contains(x.toString))
res4: String = I m tkng n ln by ln n Scl s  strng, nd I wnt t b bl t rmv ll chrctrs tht dn't blng t sm rbtrry cllctn f lttrs S.
```

Comment: More concisely, if you make `vowels` a `Set[Char]` you can write `line.filterNot(vowels)`